# C# Outlook handling ReportItems as it came?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm doing Outlook plugin in C# that gathers some system health information and logs and sends it to several email addresses of our admins and automatic analysis tools.

It mostly works well, but if some address becomes unreachanle for whatever reason users get annoyed with `ReportItems` (undelivery reports) flooding their Outlook intstances. I can think of a few ways to handle this situation, but I don't know how to implement any of them. Could you please help me?

Possible solutions:

1. Check if address is reachable before sending email. But I need to make it using Outlook features as some addresses can be accesses only by our Exchange Server and is not accessible by clients. What do you think?
2. Add some property to created `MailItems` so that Exchange Server won't send `ReportItems` if the `MailItem` wasn't delivered. But it seems that `MailItem` object doesn't have such properties, maybe there is a MAPI one I could set with PropertyAccessor or something. What do you think?
3. Intercept `ReportItems` as they are comming up with my Outlook plugin and remove them before it annoys users. But I've tried `Application.NewMailEx` event and it doesn't get called for `ReportItems` at all. I've tried `InboxFolder.ItemAdd` event and it gets called only for like 40-50% of `ReportItems`. I don't really understand the reason behind it, maybe I'm doing something wrong here. What do you think?

PS: I understand that the whole architecture of this thing is a bit ugly, but the management team insists that it is the way it should be, so I'd like to kindly ask you to answer the question as is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. AFAIK there is no reliable way to detect if any given email exists before sending to that address. Because spammers.
2. You can't control non-delivery reports from the client side (or Outlook Object Model) - that's something that can only be managed by the mail server hosting the address you are sending to.
3. The ItemAdd event is notoriously unreliable. Aside from doing periodic before and after folder scans, the only guaranteed way to effectively process changes in a folder are for Exchange Mailboxes only - see Redemption's [RDOFolderSynchronizer](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdofoldersynchronizer.htm). Another option is to use Exchange Web Services ([notification subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/notification-subscriptions-mailbox-events-and-ews-in-exchange) and possibly [transport agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/transport-agents/creating-transport-agents-for-exchange-2013)).

Answer (score 0):

The guaranteed ways described by Eric is too complex for you. I don't think you need to pay so many efforts and implement them to just handle report items. Moreover, they require an internet connection and not applicable to non-Exchange accounts. Forget about them!

I'd recommend handling report items on the recipient side where your add-in works. So, you could process them and delete if necessary.

> But I've tried Application.NewMailEx event and it doesn't get called for ReportItems at all.

That's strange! What code do you have in the `NewMailEx` event handler?

Also, you may try to handle the `NewMail` event of the `RDOSession` class (see Redemption) It is an unmanaged wrapper around Extended MAPI which provides the `NewMail` notification which is fired for all kinds of items. See [MAPI Notification Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/mapi-notification-events) for more information.

The following series of articles describes possible ways for handling incoming messages:

- [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/)
- [Outlook NewMail event: solution options](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/24/outlook-newmail-solution-options/)
- [Outlook NewMail event and Extended MAPI: C# example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/01/outlook-newmail-extended-mapi/)
- [Outlook NewMail unleashed: writing a working solution (C# example)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/)